# Is my SATA controller failing?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, freeze, sata

My Windows 10 desktop has just recently randomly started freezing up completely - any windows that are open cannot close, and opening a program does nothing. Not even task manager can open. When this happens, I am forced to hold down the power button to turn it off.

First I ran a Norton scan (ew I know), and it removed ~300 threats. All of the files it claimed were threats had a clean bill when uploaded to VirusTotal (which is weird, because Norton is one of the scanners VirusTotal uses). A Malwarebytes Anti-Malware scan confirmed the computer is clean.

I installed CrystalDiskInfo, and it says all the drives are in good condition. Here's the report: https://hastebin.com/hipalavopo.hs (I've X'd out the serial numbers, just in case).

I checked the Error Viewer, and it said something about the Windows Image Acquisition service, but I later concluded that was irrelevant because just a few minutes ago there was a crash and the only thing in the event logs was a critical notification about being hard powered off.

Also, I managed to retrieve an error from a process that was running on a tertiary SSD I have (I've got an SSD for the OS - 120GB, an SSD for a server - 60 GB, and a terabyte storage drive), and it said it was locked waiting for a file rename...

Everything important is backed up and I'm at a loss for what to do here, this computer is very important.

My guess is it's a SATA controller issue, because when the error occurs Windows 10 freezes - and the operating system is on another drive than the servers, but they both freeze. Could this be the case? What should I do to resolve this?

Thanks ahead of time for your time.

---

TL;DR Windows 10 freezes and programs can't close or open, and a server is hosted on a separate drive. Both the server and Windows freeze at the same time, as far as I'm aware (I'm never at the computer when it happens). All drives report good status, there isn't a virus or any malware on the computer.

Comment: I've run `sfc /scannow` just now, it said it found corrupt files and successfully repaired them. We'll see if that makes a difference...

Comment: Does the mouse cursor also hang? If so, it usually points to the gfx adapter. Either driver issue or hardware issue.

Comment: @Magnus The cursor and the displays are the only thing that doesn't hang.

Comment: Then my guess would also be something with the disk or controller. No further idea on a more specific solution, unfortunately...

Comment: Yeah I'm going to look at cleaning it, it's filthy on the inside...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like `sfc /scannow` has fixed it, at least for now (*knocks on wood*). Thanks to everyone who has suggested a solution!

Answer (score 0):

It definitely sounds hardware related, but picking out the SATA controller might be a bit too specific.

It's most likely you have a bad connection inside the computer on the RAM chips or some other connection. It's also very likely the system is overheating in some way. Certain systems have a lot of heat issues with certain controller chips. A surefire way that I test is to run a memory diagnostic disk (MemTest86) and gently tap on components in the computer with the plastic end of a screwdriver. If it's a bad connection, the system will absolutely freak out or lock up.

I would thoroughly clean the case with compressed air, remove and reseat the RAM chips (even better to spray the contacts with contact cleaner if you have it), and make sure all the other cables are fully seated. While the system is running for a while, look for any fans not spinning and carefully feel around for any really hot heatsinks (like too hot to touch) on the motherboard.

If the computer is more than a few years old, it could be other failing components.

Comment: In my experience, if the RAM is bad the computer is more likely to crash than hang

Comment: I've run a memory test through Windows Memory Diagnostic and it didn't report any issues. I'll look at cleaning it out, it's been awhile since it's been cleaned.

Comment: The memory test itself is not going to show a problem. It is the memory test in conjunction with the tapping of components within the computer, especially the RAM. This will reveal a crash, reboot, freeze or any number of other unpredictable results if there is an issue.

Comment: Alright I'll try that if it freezes again. I haven't had any issues since running "sfc /scannow'"

Answer (score 0):

According to the release notes of the latest Windows 10 cumulative update this might be a bug fixed (as of the day you posted this report).

I had exactly the same symptoms and came across your post, and the MS document here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/4025334/windows-10-update-kb4025334

Release notes for July 18, 2017 update for Windows 10.

"Addressed issue with a port and thread leak that can cause a broad array of symptoms including unresponsive systems and iSCSI target connection failures. This occurs after installing monthly updates released between April 11, 2017 (KB4015217) through July 11, 2017 (KB4025339). This issue was called out as known issue in the corresponding release notes for these updates.

Addressed issue where faulty silicon in Solid-State Drives impacted the performance of the Microsoft Standard NVM Express Driver (stornvme). "

That patch is not (yet) available via Windows Update, you have to use the link at the end of the document to manually download and install that build.

I was quite sure I had a failing SSD until I saw this article.  For the record my SSD is from Sandisk.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could this issue have been fixed by running `sfc \scannow`? I haven't had any issues since running that.